# Create a Dynamic Array of Vectors Using Malloc

Tags: c++, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

Hello I am attempting to learn C++, I am trying to use malloc to create an array of vectors but I cannot seem to get it to work. The vectors contain strings. I have no issue making arrays with integers but using vectors has caused me some issues. I am having the same issues with using realloc.

I am trying this, what am I doing wrong?

```
int buffer_size = 3;
int buffer_count= 0;
vector * words = (string *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(string));

//As array of vectors fills up I will add to the buffer count
if(buffer_count => buffer_size){
    words = (string*) realloc(words,buffer_size * sizeof(string));
}
```

Like I said, I must have something wrong with something in the malloc or realloc function, everything I try gives a variety of errors such as "Use of class template 'vector' requires template arguments.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>`? Vector of type `std::string`. Don't mix STL and pointers. `vector * words` is wrong. Its format is like `vector<string> words`.

Comment: if you want to learn C++ you dont want to use maloc.  A vector of strings is accomplished using `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: What you are doing wrong, is to ever use malloc/realloc/free in a C++ program, maybe unless you are an advanced library developer or interfacing C code. The same goes for new/delete

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` and other STL containers are meant to remove the complexities caused by using pointers and dynamic memory allocation, such as memory leaks, undefined behavior invoked by accessing data out-of-bound, etc.

`std::vector` is dynamic in itself. The more you `emplace_back` or `push_back`, the more it grows. If you want a vector that contains strings of variable length, why not declare it like this:

```
std::vector<String> words {"Hello", "World"};
```

Similarly, you can create multidimensional vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Type>> doubleContainer {};
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a template class, but you are trying to use it without specifying any values for its template arguments. That is why you are getting errors.

However, you can't assign a `string*` pointer to a `vector*` pointer, like you are trying to do. Your `words` variable needs to be declared as `string*` instead. At least then the code will compile.

However, the code won't behave correctly at runtime, because the `malloc()`/`realloc()` functions are from the C runtime library, but `std::string` is a C++ non-trivial class that requires construction, and the C functions do not call class constructors.  So, you would have to use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to solve that problem (and forget about using `realloc()`, as there is no safe way to realloc memory that is also placement-new'ed), eg:

```
string *words = (string*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(string));
for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
    new(&words[i]) string;
}
...
if (buffer_count >= buffer_size) {
    int new_buffer_size = buffer_size * 2;
    string *new_words = (string*) malloc(new_buffer_size * sizeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
        new(&new_words[i]) string(words[i]);
    }
    for (int i = buffer_size; i < new_buffer_size; ++i) {
        new(&new_words[i]) string();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
        words[i].~string();
    }
    free(words);
    words = new_words;
    buffer_size = new_buffer_size;
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
    words[i].~string();
}
free(words);
```

In which case, it is better/safer to use `new[]`/`delete[]` instead:

```
string * words = new string[buffer_size];
...
if (buffer_count >= buffer_size) {
    int new_buffer_size = buffer_size * 2;
    string *new_words = new string[new_buffer_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
        new_words[i] = words[i];
    }
    delete[] words;
    words = new_words;
    buffer_size = new_buffer_size;
}
...
delete[] words;
```

Or, just use `std::vector` properly and let it handle all of the dynamic memory management for you:

```
vector<string> words;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using malloc to allocate memory for a vector of strings, but malloc only allocates raw memory, which means you can't directly use it to create an array of vectors. Instead, you need to use the `new` keyword.

```
vector<string> *words = new vector<string>[buffer_size];
```

You're trying to cast the return value of malloc to a vector*, but this is not allowed. Instead, you can use the vector class's `reserve` method to allocate the necessary amount of memory for the vectors in the array, and then use the `emplace_back` method to add new elements to the array.

```
if (buffer_count >= buffer_size) {
  words->reserve(buffer_size * 2);
  words->emplace_back();
}
```

Hope this helps!